# How to invoke validate method in Validator class

Tags: java

I've been scratching my head because I can't seem to invoke the method the usual way.

Basically I have to create a program for buying insurance policy. The Policy class contains the attributes with getter and setter methods. I have a Validator class where I validate each of the attributes for policy name, policy type, tenure, policy number etc.. Now the problem is how to **invoke the validate method** in the InsuranceService class to when a person buys a policy?

Validator class - each sub-validate method (eg. vallidatePolicyName() is created and return as true or false but I'm leaving it out here)

```
public static void validate(Policy policy) throws Exception{ 
try{ 
  if(!vallidatePolicyName(policy.getPolicyName())){ 
    throw new Exception("Validator.INVALID_POLICY_NAME");
  }
  else if (!vallidatePolicyType(policy.getPolicyType())){
    throw new Exception("Validator.INVALID_POLICY_TYPE");
  }
  else if (!vallidateTenure(policy.getTenure())){
    throw new Exception("Validator.INVALID_TENURE");
  }
  else if (!vallidatePolicyNumber(policy.getPolicyNumber())){
    throw new Exception("Validator.INVALID_POLICY_NUMBER");
  }
}
catch(Exeception e){ 
  System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
}
}
```

Here I need to invoke the validate(Policy policy) method as shown above

```
public class InsuranceService{ 
  pubic String buyPolicy(Policy policy) throws Exception{ 
    new Policy().validate(policy); // or policy.validate(policy); will not work 
  } 
}
```

Can anyone be able to advise me the right way to invoke the method? Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Are both the methods in same class?

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi  Nope, the validate() method is in the Validator class while the buyPolicy() method is in the InsuranceService class where I need to invoke the validate() method

Comment: [The way to call looks valid.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L7h4WaCOhm2CgABU). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including desired and actual behaviors.

Comment: You should then call it like Validator.validate(policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information, I infer that you're trying to invoke the validate method of the Validator class.

Also, sounds like you have to grasp the concept of static and instance in OOPS. First I will give you an overview of the concept and then the answer.

There are two types of method and fields in Java.

**Object/Instance Method and Fields:**

- This is limited to the scope of individual objects of that class.
- You cannot call this method/Fields with that class name.
- The value present for a field in one object will not affect the value of others

**Static Methods and Fields:**

- This belongs to the class scope and it is shared across all objects of that class.
- If one objects change the field value, it will also reflect on other objects
- **Static Fields can be called from the objects of that class but the static method can only be invoked from the defined class**

**Solution**

The validate is a static method located in Validator class, So you have to call
(`Validator.validate(policy)`).